# How to style a part of the Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Text` widget and I want to make a part of it `bold`. How can I do that?

Example: `Text("Required interests: Music, Guitar")`

I want "Required interests:" to be bold and rest to be normal.

Comment: `Text.rich(...)` / `RichText(...)`

Comment: @Morez don't forget to mark a answer  as "accepted answer" if it solve your problem. So that others will see it as a answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Text.rich()` to achieve this.

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Required interests: ',
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Music, Guitar',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      )
    ]
  ),
);
```

Note if you do not specify any style in any of the `children`'s `TextSpan` it will use the parent's style.